# sumproduct based on columns with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame containing both numeric values as well as `NaN` values. I would like to somehow apply a weighted sum, with the weights specified within another DataFrame (a single row 'weighting scheme') as such:

```
df =    

                     Score_1     Score_2     Score 3     Score 4     Score_5
0                    1.0         6.0         3.0         10.0        8.0  
1                    5.0         NaN         9.0         NaN         1.0
2                    10.0        NaN         NaN         5.0         3.0
...

weights
                     Score_1        Score_2        Score_4
0                    0.25           0.70           0.05
```

The `NaN` values are to be treated as `1`. I would like the result to become a new column, `Wgt_sum`, in the original DataFrame, yielding

```
df =    

                     Score_1     Score_2     Score 3     Score 4    Score_5    Wgt_sum 
0                    1.0         6.0         3.0         10.0       8.0        4.95
1                    5.0         NaN         9.0         NaN        1.0        2.0
2                    10.0        NaN         NaN         5.0        3.0        3.45
...
```

Note that `Wgt_sum` is supposed to be composed only of columns `Score_1`, `Score_2` and `Score_4` - as specified in the `weights` DataFrame, and that the `NaN` values has been used with a `1`.

Moreover, the columns in `weights` can be different from the ones specified, and hence I would like a "general" solution where `weights`'s columns are used within both `df` and `weights`...

Any smart solution for this one?

Thanks

Comment: Am I correct in saying that the `weights` dataframe has the same number of rows as the `df` dataframe?

Comment: Unfortunately no. As of now it is only composed of a single row - but of course I suppose it can be extended or altered with the same values in order to have the same size as df...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the same weight for every row of df, then really weights should be a Series and not a DataFrame because its index isn't carrying any information.  So:

```
In [152]: df["Wgt_sum"] = (df.fillna(1) * weights.iloc[0]).sum(axis=1)

In [153]: df
Out[153]: 
   Score_1  Score_2  Score 3  Score 4  Score_5  Wgt_sum
0      1.0      6.0      3.0     10.0      8.0     4.95
1      5.0      NaN      9.0      NaN      1.0     2.00
2     10.0      NaN      NaN      5.0      3.0     3.45
```

where the `.iloc[0]` is just selecting the first row of weights.

We can confirm that it's aligning correctly by looking at the pre-sum output:

```
In [165]: df.fillna(1) * weights.iloc[0]
Out[165]: 
   Score 3  Score 4  Score_1  Score_2  Score_5
0      NaN     0.50     0.25      4.2      NaN
1      NaN     0.05     1.25      0.7      NaN
2      NaN     0.25     2.50      0.7      NaN
```

The index labels of `weights.iloc[0]` have matched the columns of `df`.

Comment: Hi @DSM - will this only use the columns that are matched? So that I am not risking of having the result as:

df.Score_1 * weights.Score_1 (correct) + 
df.Score_2 * weights.Score_2 (correct) + 
df.Score_3 * weights.Score_4 (wrong)

Comment: @gussilago: yep.

Comment: @gussilago But it will only work if your column names actually match (in your dataframe it is called `"Score 4"`, but in your weights it is called `"Score_4"`).